# ServiceStack: Will there be an OnBeforeExecuteAsync?

Tags: asynchronous, service, servicestack

I have a ServiceStack Service with a baseclass, and I was hoping to execute some code "OnBeforeExecute", like below. However, I am mostly encountering async methods that needs to be awaited, and generally, this is something I try to follow everywhere (async everywhere). This becomes a problem though, because the OnBeforeExecute does not exist as an awaitable:

```
public override void OnBeforeExecute(object requestDto)
{
    base.OnBeforeExecute(requestDto);
    await Redis.GetAsync<Test>("asd"); // <-- async example call
}
```

Is there plans to introduce an `virtual Task OnBeforeExecute(object requestDto)` to remedy this, or do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an async [Global Request Filter](https://docs.servicestack.net/request-and-response-filters#async) or async [Filter attribute](https://docs.servicestack.net/filter-attributes).

From **v5.10.4+** your Services can implement `IServiceBeforeFilterAsync` to execute `OnBeforeExecuteAsync()` before each request, e.g:

```
public class MyServices : Service, IServiceBeforeFilterAsync 
{
    public Task OnBeforeExecuteAsync(object requestDto)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, the OnBeforeExecute is a Service override, the GlobalRequestFiltersAsync.Add needs to be added in the Configure method, outside of the Service class. It is cleaner and more contained, I think, if I can choose to override the OnBeforeExecuteAsync in the Service class, and not generally for all types of services?

Comment: Could I ask you to consider introducing an overload `OnBeforeExecuteAsync`? Otherwise, it becomes messy and those methods loose their usage as awaitable calls gain more and more ground.

Comment: All feature requests should be submitted to https://servicestack.uservoice.com so demand for it can be measured & the feature prioritized. I've added a `IServiceBeforeFilterAsync` interface your services can implement `OnBeforeExecuteAsync`, available in latest v5.10.3 on MyGet

Comment: Thanks. What I did was to simply add the interface to my base class, like `public abstract class CoreModuleServiceBase: Service, IServiceBeforeFilterAsync` and then implement the method, but the method isn't called called / never fired. What am I missing? =)

Comment: @Ted I've tested it, it's definitely getting called. I'd do a clean build, remove `bin/` and `obj/` folders and make sure all projects have been upgraded to the latest v5.10.3 on MyGet.

Comment: Alright, some cleaning did it. Sorry. And thanks again for the quick remedy!